# Is it possible to design a three-phase delta generator only with two generators?

Tags: generator, three-phase

I've always seen 3 generators in a three-phase generator, but this question came to my mind. I've tried to add an element instead of the third generator, although with no result.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: A three-phase delta generator is one generator with two or more poles per each of the three phases. The output is three voltages 120° apart. Are you asking, "*Can you make a 3-phase generator using only two windings?*" If so, then please edit your question using the link below it. "*I've tried to add an element ...*" What does this mean? Add a diagram.

Comment: @Transistor, what do you mean be poles? Well, I know what is a pole in a filter, but I don't know the element that you're reffering. On the other hand, I deliberately wrote _two generators_. Finally, _an element_ means an impedance, a capacitor, a coil... I've thought in several elements, but I don't know if that's right.

Comment: OK, you are missing some fundamental terminology about AC generators. A three-phase generator is considered one generator (although it has three windings and three outputs) so your question is unclear.

Comment: You are using "generator" in the sense of an electromechanical generator, that turns rotational, mechanical energy into electrical power, yes?  Because if you're talking about signal generators, you need to let us know.  An example schematic, or link to an example article, would help us to help you.

Comment: Are you talking about a simulation rather than a physical generator? In that case, you do need three generators although you may be able to create an "open delta" with just two generators or two generators and a large impedance.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the three phases of an isolated floating 'three phase' generator, driving a balanced three phase load with no neutral.

Now ground one of the phases.

We still have three phases, with the same voltages between them. The balanced three phase load will still draw the same power, still see the same phase to phase voltages.

However, we only have two phases which are not at ground potential. So we can drive these two phases with two suitably phased single phase generators.

I've often done this to drive a 3 phase synchro from my 2 channel sound card, generate two tones with 60 degrees phase shift between them, and use ground as the third phase.